# monaco editor matchBrackets do not highlight

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm defining new language in [monaco-editor](/questions/tagged/monaco-editor). I expect that it automatically highlight matching brackets and parentheses because by default `matchBrackets` option is true.

Should I do anything else?

**Sample Code:**
Look at [this page](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html) it doesn't work in Microsoft's samples codes too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see the original TypeScript source for the `java` language defined at:

https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-languages/blob/master/src/java/java.ts

The Compiled JavaScript looks like:

[image: Language]

If you see, what you need is not part of the language as such but part of the config of that language.

So If I open the console window on the `Monarch` [demo link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html) and execute below

```js
config = {"surroundingPairs":[{"open":"{","close":"}"}],"autoClosingPairs":[{"open":"{","close":"}"}],"brackets":[["{","}"]]}
monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration("monarch-language-mylang", config)
```

The auto-matching of brackets starts working as shown below

[image: config]

[image: Matching works]

So you need to make sure to set the config as well for your language

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: the link is broken too

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is an issue with matching bracket on monaco editor version 0.34.0 just npm install monaco-editor@0.33.0 until this is solved

Comment: Please use the code hightlighting option, ex `Hi There`